# Magento 1.9 - Show Custom Attribute value after availability status on product detail page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, custom

Created a custom attribute and assigned it to all attribute set for Magento 1.9 Sample Data. I have set `Visible on Product View page` and `Product Listing page` to `YES`.

[image: attribute]

Assigned attribute value to product as shown below

[image: Product Points]

The attribute value is shown under additional information on product details page. How do I show it as shown in below image using layout. Which block do I need to change ? My extension resides under `app/code/local/`

[image: points details]

Comment: does solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused a bit. You state you created a custom attribute. You then speak of using an extension in app/code/local. Why do you need an extension for placing an attribute?

Have you considered adding to `/app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` something like this?

```
<p>YOU WILL EARN <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('customer_product_points') ?> POINTS FOR PURCHASING THIS PRODUCT.</p>
```

Comment: I am able to display the attribute but not at the specified location. Rest is done.

Comment: Make sure <?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?> appears in the beginning of the document.

Answer (score 1):

Add following code to inject custom attribute on **Product Detail Page**.

Add following code in your `module.xml` of frontend.

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.addtocart">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="block.view">
        <block type="module/block" name="block.cart.view" as ="blockview" template="Namespace/Module/cart/view.phtml"/> 
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Create file: `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\namespace\module\cart\view.phtml`

And add following code in `view.phtml` -

```
<?php
$_proId= Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_proId);
$CustomAttribute= $_product->getData('custom_attribute');
echo $CustomAttribute;    
?>
```